# Entity Framework, why is this sql being generated?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When I look at the SQL query generated by EF I see

```
SELECT [extent1].ID as ID,
[extent1].Name as Name 
From( 
Select myview.ID as ID,
myview.Name as Name
From myview) AS [extent1]
Where([Extent1].ID = @p_linq_0)
```

Why is the outside select happening on the inside select? I've got a very large table that I can get a record from easily with the outside query but the whole query combined times out.

My Linq query

```
var result = from i in invitationEntity.Invitations
.Where(a=>a.id == inviationId)
select i;
```

I am using SQL 2012 & EF5 & Linq.

Is there a way to "force" the simpler query?

Comment: I'm rather curious to see what you find. I don't know why EF is doing this, but I am a little suprised that the query optimizer isn't generating the same plan for both. Is the view sql you have here just very simplified? I tried running this on some tables and views of my own, and I get the same execution plan for both queries.

Comment: The above works if you have <2 million records but if you have 29 million it is subject to timeouts. I did simplify the fields being returned. I'm beginning to think it's less EF and more Linq to Entities that is the culprit.

Comment: is this code first, db first, model first?

Comment: This is a DB first project.

Comment: What is select I for lol. The SQL generated is what you told it to generate don't blame EF

Answer (score 5):

Because you are calling "SELECT" once again at the end along with LINQ method.

```
var result = from i in invitationEntity.Invitations
.Where(a=>a.id == inviationId)
select i;
```

The last line select i, is useless, but EF is not aware of it whether it has anything useful or not, you can simply avoid it.

```
var result = invitationEntity.Invitations
.Where(a=>a.id == inviationId);
```

You can still enumerate result and get everything.

Ok sorry, I forgot to add, you don't have to use "from", you can simply use .Where(expression )

And if you want to use LINQ keywords, then you can use it this way,

```
var result = from i in invitationEntity.Invitations
where i.id == invitationId
select i;
```

You cannot mix LINQ keywords and LINQ extension methods.

Comment: You have to end the query body with a select clause. If there is another way I would love to hear about it.

Comment: You don't need to use from i either, and you have mixed LINQ keywords and LINQ methods.

Comment: I ran the query var result = Invitations.Where(i=>i.id == "123456"); Result.Dump(); thru LinqPad and I get the exact same SQL with the nested selects.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that

```
   var result = from i in invitationEntity.Invitations
               .Where(a=>a.id == inviationId)
                select i;
```

this

```
    a=>a.id == inviationId
```

from `a=>` generate

```
  Select myview.ID as ID,
  myview.Name as Name
  From myview
```

so `a` is [extent1]

you should use a "standard" where clause

```
           from i in invitationEntity.Invitations
                  where i.id == inviationId
            select i;
```

Comment: This generated the exact same SQL.